# Calling base class method from instance creating using type function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Normally, a base class method in Python can be called from a derived class the same way any derived class function is called:

```
class Base:
    def base_method(self):
        print("Base method")

class Foo(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

f = Foo()
f.base_method()
```

However, when I create a class dynamically using the `type` function, I am unable to call base class methods without passing in a `self` instance:

```
class Base:
    def base_method(self):
        print("Base method")

f = type("Foo", (Base, object), { "abc" : "def" })
f.base_method() # Fails
```

This raises a TypeError: `TypeError: base_method() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`

It works if I explicitly pass a `self` parameter:

```
f.base_method(f)
```

Why is it necessary to explicitly pass the `self` instance when calling a base class method?

Comment: No sense having `class Foo(Base):...` in your second example.

Comment: Probably it'is a cut&paste error.

Comment: @Bakuriu -- Probably.  I just thought I would point it out.  Depending on exactly what OP thinks `type` does, he might believe that it is necessary there and that somehow `f` and the class `Foo` are related (since they have the same `__name__` after all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your line `f = type(...)` returns a class, not an instance.

If you do `f().base_method()`, it should work.

Answer (score 2):

`type` return a class not an instance. You should instantiate the class before calling `base_method`:

```
>>> class Base(object):
...     def base_method(self): print 'a'
... 
>>> f = type('Foo', (Base,), {'arg': 'abc'})
>>> f.base_method()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method base_method() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
>>> f().base_method()
a
```